# expand/collapsing levels in Microsoft Edge not functioning.

Tags: getorgchart

This problem can be observed on the demo page of the website (http://www.getorgchart.com/Demos).
Nodes disappear, and a node appears before the start of the tree structure.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been addressed in the latest version 2.5.0